# Ordenação de linhas numa tabela com SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela (Customer) exemplo:

> ```
> ID  Nome   Order
> 1   Joao   1
> 2   Ana    2
> 3   Marta  3
> 4   Joana  4
> ```

O objetivo é ordenar os conteudos da seguinte forma: Recebo o ID (@ID) da posição a mudar e a nova posição (@novaOrdem) para esse ID.

- Se receber, por exemplo, o ID 1 para a 4ª posição, os dados devem ficar (Ana Marta Joana Joao)
- Se receber, por exemplo, ID 3 para a posição 1, os dados devem ficar (Marta Joao Ana joana)

Consegui resolver o meu problema usando um cursor (código seguinte), no entanto gostaria de saber se havia de resolver sem a utilização do cursor.

```
 DECLARE  @idC BIGINT,
  @ordem INT,
  @OldOrdem INT,
  @cont INT = 1;--cont tem que ser 1 para adicionar +1

  SET @OldOrdem = (SELECT Order FROM Customer WHERE ID = @ID)
 IF(@OldOrdem < @novaOrdem)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Ordem_Cursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT ID, Order FROM Customer WHERE Order <= @novaOrdem AND ID <> @ID AND Order<>0 ORDER BY Order ASC
            UPDATE Customer SET Order = @novaOrdem  WHERE ID = @ID; /*parametro*/
            OPEN Ordem_Cursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM Ordem_Cursor INTO @idC , @ordem 
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
              BEGIN
            UPDATE  Customer SET Order = @cont WHERE ID = @idC AND Order<>0
            SET @cont = @cont + 1 
             FETCH NEXT FROM Ordem_Cursor INTO @idC , @ordem
            END;
        CLOSE Ordem_Cursor
        DEALLOCATE Ordem_Cursor
     END
ELSE
 BEGIN
    DECLARE Ordem_Cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT ID, Order FROM Customer WHERE Order >= @novaOrdem  AND ID <> @ID  AND Order<>0 ORDER BY Order ASC-- selecionar os campos da tabela da mesma page e por ordem crescente
        UPDATE Customer SET Order = @novaOrdem  WHERE ID = @ID; /*parametro*/
        OPEN Ordem_Cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM Ordem_Cursor INTO @idC , @ordem 
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
          BEGIN
        UPDATE  Customer SET Order = @novaOrdem + @cont WHERE ID = @idC AND Order<>0
        SET @cont = @cont + 1 
         FETCH NEXT FROM Ordem_Cursor INTO @idC , @ordem
        END;
    CLOSE Ordem_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE Ordem_Cursor
END
```

alguém me sabe dizer se é possível?
Cumps

Comment: Não entendi bem a regra de ordenação mas muitas vezes um CASE no ORDER BY , algo como ORDER BY (CASEN WHEN P_ORDEM='N' THEN NOME ELSE CODIGO END) , ou seja ordenaria conforme um parametro passado.

Comment: O que você realmente precisa é deixar os dados já ordenados na tabela ou quando realizar uma consulta obter os mesmos ordenados?

Answer (score 1):

Talvez eu esteja sendo muito simplista, mas você consegue fazer essa ordenação com 2 `updates` condicionais:

```sql
DECLARE @idC BIGINT,
    @novaOrdem INT,
    @oldOrdem INT;
SET @idC=1;
SET @novaOrdem=4;
--Obtém a Ordem do ID que estamos alterando
SET @oldOrdem=(SELECT Order FROM Customer WHERE ID=@idC);
--Se for mover para baixo (@oldOrdem < @novaOrdem), quem estiver no intervalo sobe 1
UPDATE Customer SET Order=Order-1 WHERE @oldOrdem < @novaOrdem AND Order BETWEEN @oldOrdem+1 AND @novaOrdem;
--Se for mover para cima (@oldOrdem > @novaOrdem), quem estiver no intervalo desce 1
UPDATE Customer SET Order=Order+1 WHERE @oldOrdem > @novaOrdem AND Order BETWEEN @novaOrdem AND @oldOrdem-1;
--Coloca o ID no destino
UPDATE Customer SET Order=@novaOrdem WHERE ID=@idC;
```